# 【gdb】【list】what does the second line of echo mean

Tags: gdb

when i use `list *func+offset` to view src in gdb, the second line of echo make me confused, what's the relationship between line 304 and `*rte_ring_create_elem+0x1cc`.

```
(gdb) l *rte_ring_create_elem+0x1cc
0x9f744 is in rte_ring_create_elem (src/lib/librte_ring/rte_ring.c:309).
304   src/lib/librte_ring/rte_ring.c: No such file or directory.
```

below is the dpdk src with line number.

```
294         mz = rte_memzone_reserve_aligned(mz_name, ring_size, socket_id,
295                                          mz_flags, __alignof__(*r));
296         if (mz != NULL) {
297                 r = mz->addr;
298                 /* no need to check return value here, we already checked the
299                  * arguments above */
300                 rte_ring_init(r, name, requested_count, flags);
301 
302                 te->data = (void *) r;
303                 r->memzone = mz;
304 
305                 TAILQ_INSERT_TAIL(ring_list, te, next);
306         } else {
307                 r = NULL;
308                 RTE_LOG(ERR, RING, "Cannot reserve memory\n");
309                 rte_free(te);
310         }
311         rte_mcfg_tailq_write_unlock();
```

I have tried to secarh the answer, but there are all the usage guide for `list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `list *` command lists (by default) 10 lines of source code around the address in the binary you specified.

In your case, you specified the symbolic address `rte_ring_create_elem+0x1cc`, so gdb helpfully prints the actual address that is (0x9f744) and tells you that corresponds to line 309 in rte_ring.c.  It then tries to show 10 lines around that (lines 304-313), but it can't find the source file, so gives the error you see.